# Training distributed on AI engine is slowed down because the evaluation is not distributed

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, google-cloud-ml

We have been training a neural net on the AI engine with a data-set consisting of 96 000 000 data points. The neural net was trained in a distributed manner, and as customary we used 20 % of the data-set as evaluation data. In order to train distributed we used TensorFlow estimators and the method tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate. Since our data-set is very large, our evaluation set is also quite large. Looking into the cpu usage of the master vs the workers nodes, and testing with an evaluation data-set consisting of only 100 samples, it appears as though the evaluation is not distributed and happens only on the master node. This makes the amount of ML units consumed increase by a factor of approximately 5 between having the standard size evaluation data (20 % of the total data) and only having 100 data points for evaluation, while the amount of training data is the same.

We see two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Doing also the evaluation distributed, but is that technically possible on the AI platform?
2. Finding a representative smaller evaluation data-set. Is there a best practice approach to build this smaller data-set?

Below is what I think is the relevant part of the code. The function input_fn returns a tf.data.Dataset that has been batched.

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_steps=1000, keep_checkpoint_max=10, tf_random_seed=random_seed
    )

    myestimator = _get_estimator(
        hidden_neurons, run_config, learning_rate, output_dir, my_rmse
    )

    # input_fn for tf.estimator Spec must be a callable function without args.
    # So we pack our input_fn in a lambda function
    callable_train_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        filenames=train_paths,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        batch_size=train_batch_size,
        num_parallel_reads=num_parallel_reads,
        random_seed=random_seed,
        input_format=input_format,
    )
    callable_eval_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(
        filenames=eval_paths,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        batch_size=eval_batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        num_parallel_reads=num_parallel_reads,
        random_seed=random_seed,
        input_format=input_format,
    )

    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
        input_fn=callable_train_input_fn, max_steps=max_steps_train
    )

    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn=callable_eval_input_fn,
        steps=max_steps_eval,
        throttle_secs=throttle_secs,
        exporters=[exporter],
        name="taxifare-eval",
    )

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(myestimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Comment: If you are doing asynchronous training (with parameter server), the evaluation on master (chief) will not block the training on workers. Can you provide more details about how you are doing the training please?

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the code to the question. We are doing asynchonous training as we are using tensorflow estimators and the method tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate. We basically tried to  followed what was written here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/distributed-training-details

Comment: Are you training with GPUs or TPUs?

Comment: As per your question on test size. The 20% is outdated. That is for small datasets. The larger the dataset, the less percentage is needed for test (holdout). The test set simply needs to be representative (sampling) distribution of the dataset (population). For 96M examples, 1 to 2% should suffix.

Comment: So you say that as long as you have a random sample of 1-2 % of the data set it is sufficient.

Comment: I am simply training on CPU as I have only one hidden layer and then you don't gain much from GPU or TPU

Comment: Correct. Typically 100K size dataset is small, and one uses 20% for test. Under a million, 10% is used. At 10M, one uses about 5% and by the time dataset is at/above 100M, one uses 1 to 2%.

Comment: For CPUs (and TPUs), the evaluation won't be distributed. It is if one is using GPUs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202884/discussion-between-helga-holmestad-and-andrew-opengeocode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the comments and investigating a little more it looks like the evaluation is not slowing down the process, but the evaluation happens twice (once during the training and always at the end of the training). Therefore the training time is longer simply because one has to wait for the evaluation to finish. Thanks for all the comments

Answer (score 1):

`TF` isn't that comfy for distributed learning. Check out [mxnet](https://mxnet.apache.org/). There's nice intro [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/11/13/how-to-install-mxnet-for-deep-learning/).